# Cannot find module "node-sass" react

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am trying to build `react` app and I want to use `scss` to style my app.

**Challenge is that even though I already installed node-sass, but I still get this error.**

```sh
./src/styles/styles.scss (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/styles/styles.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/getDefaultSassImplementation.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/getSassImplementation.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

I also tried to delete `node_modules` and reinstalled `node-sass` but it didn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me sometimes and seems like issue with npm. Try installing `node-sass` using yarn

```
yarn add node-sass
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to answer this question directly!

But point to an important matter! `node-sass` is **deprecated**!

`sass` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) is used now in react-scripts. And the whole sass compiler or pre-processor is followed in the [Dart sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) project!

**sass** package is a **distribution** of **Dart sass**!

You can check more details and illustration in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327656/7668448

Answer (score 1):

This really seems like issue with npm (it happend not always), but if you already use `npm` to your project, it would be better to use:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

instead of relocating all dependencies on `yarn`.