# Cannot find module 'sass'

Tags: reactjs, docker, sass

I wrote a *React* app and tried to *dockerize* it.
After I do this it doesn't compile correctly, it doesn't find the `sass` module and the error is:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/index.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-
> 1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-
> oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
> Cannot find module 'sass' Require stack:
>
> - /app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js
> - /app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js
> - /app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
> - /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
> - /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
> - /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
> - /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
> - /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
> - /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
> - /app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

and this is my *dockerfile*:

```
From node:14.16.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@4.0.3 -g --silent

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and I don't have *docker-compose*.

any solution?

I add this line to my docker file but it doesn't work and gets me the same Error:

```
RUN npm install -g sass
```

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the docker, it's more kind of webpack problem or just packages

Comment: but it works correctly before duckerizing!

Comment: You must had `sass` installed globally so. Try to install it in your docker `npm i -g sass`

Comment: i install it globaly but doesn't work!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To note! `node-sass` is deprecated as by now!

> Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass).

[image]

Instead you can see that Sass is followed on the **Dart sass** project!

**react-scripts** already moved that direction!

[image]

The used package now is **sass**! `npm i -g sass` or `npm i sass --save-dev`

If you go to npm `sass` [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)

[image]

> This package is a **distribution** of **Dart Sass**, compiled to pure JavaScript with no native code or external dependencies. It provides a command-line sass executable and a Node.js API.

> You can install Sass globally using `npm install -g sass` **which will provide access to the sass executable**. You can also add it to your project using `npm install --save-dev sass`. **This provides the executable as well as a library**.

### What should be done

Install `sass`

Globally

```
npm i -g sass
```

or

Locally

```
npm i sass --save-dev
```

I personally prefer to always go with local installs! So that `npm install` will add it automatically! Sometimes too to maintain the versions per project!

And

[image]

[image]

App compilling and running after install!

### old version of react scripts

If you are running on an old version that require node-sass!

Then you can Update to the latest version! And before that! You may like to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

```
npm i react-scripts --save
```

After that `npm install` to install again the project dependencies

And you can go for installing `sass` step

Comment: I confirm that installing locally fixed my issue: npm i sass --save-dev in project folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install sass
```

Answer (score 9):

To be clear:

1st) try uninstalling it by using this command

`npm uninstall node-sass`

and then 2nd) try installing sass

`npm install --save-dev sass`

this worked for me when I was having issues installing sass on a project using create react app

Answer (score 5):

I solve it!
you just need to add this line in to your "dockerfile" so when you build your docker image it should install sass automaticly:

```
RUN npm install -g sass
```

and in your "package.json" add this in the "dependencies" that it tells to program what we have in this case we mean we have the specific version of "sass":

```
"sass": "version number(example:^5.0.0)"
```

and add this in "scripts" part that tells to program how to work in this case I think it tells that for "scss" files whatch that file and recognize and open it like a "css":

```
"scss": "sass --whatch scss -o css"
```

Answer (score 4):

### How to add support for SCSS and SCSS modules in Webpack

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader style-loader css-loader mini-css-extract-plugin
```

Source: https://www.developerhandbook.com/webpack/how-to-configure-scss-modules-for-webpack/#how-to-add-support-for-scss-and-scss-modules-in-webpack

Answer (score 3):

Try install in your terminal this

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

and restart your localhost by typing

```
npm start
```

**Hit Enter on your prompt**

After doing these steps make sure to check your dependency go into

> package.json

and find

> "devDependencies": {
> "node-sass": "^yourversion"   }

Answer (score 2):

**First install sass Globally OR Locally**

**Globally** : `npm i -g sass`

**Locally** :`npm i sass --save-dev`

*Check package.json file for sass dependency if it is not present there try adding it manually.*

**Check sass version** : `npm sass --version`

**In package.json File**

1. Add this in dependency section: `"sass": "^version-number"`
2. Add this in scripts section: `"scss": "sass --whatch scss -o css"`

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqOgR.png)

I have added
"devDependencies": {
"sass": "^1.66.1"
}
at the end in package.json
stop server
run npm install
run npm start
it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem and i fixed by executing : `yarn add sass --dev`