# Angular material: SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mat": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core();"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I had an angular 11 project working for a while with angular material (also 11). I just updated everything to angular 12 (including material). The styles.scss that is included with material is now failing after the update. The entire error is:

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mat": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core();"
        on line 11 of src/styles.scss
>> @include mat.core();

   ---------^

    at processResult (/Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:676:19)
    at /Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:778:5
    at /Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.callback (/Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7)
    at Object.done [as callback] (/Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8069:18)
    at options.error (/Users/ronnieswietek/Sites/elysian-finder/modules/custom/elysian_finder/finder/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:293:32)

./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[1].use[1]!./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mat": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core();"
        on line 11 of src/styles.scss
>> @include mat.core();

   ---------^
```

The code in question that is failing is:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core(); // <--- Here is where it is failing.

$finder-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$finder-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);
$finder-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$finder-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $finder-primary,
    accent: $finder-accent,
    warn: $finder-warn,
  )
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include mat.all-component-themes($finder-theme);
```

I've searched their issue queue and cant seem to find anything. I saw a couple suggestions to run `npm rebuild node-sass`. That didn't work. I also did an `npm install node-sass` and that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: ah it was simple, make sure the use statement comes before the import!

Comment: Same problem here, and "use" is before "import".

Comment: I bring @use in top of scss class but Error still appear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652012/sasserror-cant-find-stylesheet-to-import-use-angular-material-as-mat

Answer (score 16):

I fixed it by removing node sass all together.

`npm uninstall node-sass`

Comment: This answer fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

node-sass is deprecated in 2021. I had the same issue as in the question and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327656/12532248 helped me

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by installing [npm sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) (this might not have been required).

I also had to move the following code out of my **/styles/_theme.scss** and place it directly into my **styles.scss**. Seems there is an issue with **@include mat.core()** in partial scss files (files that start with _).

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat.core();

$app-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$app-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);

$app-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette, 900);

$app-theme: mat.define-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

@include mat.all-component-themes($app-theme);

$sansserif-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: sans-serif
);
@include mat.all-component-typographies($sansserif-typography);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I tried adding my similar code above to my root scss file. I will try to get it back into a partial through experimentation etc.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall node-sass as mentioned in the other answers.

`npm uninstall node-sass`

You don't need to install sass separately, this should already be used internally in material.

Second, this might seem unrelated but it has worked for me. The `.browserslistrc` file needs to be using the new format. By default in Angular 12 this should be:

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# For the full list of supported browsers by the Angular framework, please see:
# https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

The old format somehow causes node-sass to be still used so the `@use` statements end up failing.

The old format looks something like this for me:

[image]

There is discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20967

Lastly, ensure the `@use` statements are placed before any @import statements (at the top of the file).

Answer (score 0):

After going through a lot of solutions this is what worked for me:

1. uninstall node-sass: **npm uninstall node-sass**
2. delete *node-modules* folder and *package-lock.json* file
3. install sass: **npm install --save-dev sass**
4. npm install
5. npm start

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `node-sass` on your `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, and you still are seeing this error or in the build you see the warning that node-sass is deprecated: Check if you're projects parent folder have the `node_modules` folder with `node-sass`.

That was my case, so I removed the `node_modules` because in my case the parent folder didn't need that folder, or remove `node-sass` from the parent folder npm project, depending on what you need.