# angular 12, sass, not recognizing "@use '~@angular/material' as mat;" and then "mat.define-typography-config"

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, node-sass

I am updating to Angular 12 from Angular 11. During `ng serve`, I am unable to compile this: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#define-a-level

## Backtrace

```
./src/custom-theme.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...typography: mat": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".define-typography-"
        on line 5 of src/custom-theme.scss
>> $custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(

   -----------------------^
```

## custom-theme.scss

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;

$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Lato, Helvetica'
);
@include mat.core($custom-typography);
...
```

My `package.json` has `"node-sass": "^4.14.1",`

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. @use '~@angular/material' as mat;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652012/sasserror-cant-find-stylesheet-to-import-use-angular-material-as-mat), [Angular material: SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mat": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core();"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67527236/8017690)