# Why can't the compiler find the Sass module?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass

I have a project where I imported a Sass file. Why, then, am I getting this error?

```
Failed to compile.

./src/styles/facebook.scss (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/styles/facebook.scss)
Cannot find module 'sass'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\utils.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
```

Comment: Please check the following Stack overflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327656/3073842

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you clear the npm cache :: npm cache clear --force

Comment: 1. I'm on Yarn, so I used `yarn cache clean`. 2. Still didn't work.