# SASS compilation error in Bootstrap after upgrading to React 18

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

After upgrading React from `17.0.2` to `18.2.0` application does not compile anymore due to  SASS compilation error, which looks like this:

```
SassError: property "url" must be followed by a ':'
        on line 6 of node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>> size:1.25rem;--bs-navbar-toggler-icon-bg:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg x
   ------------------------------------------^
```

There are Bootstrap and `node-sass` packages that I use:

```
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1"
```

I did not update versions of any other packages except for `react` and `react-dom`, although I tried updating `bootstrap`, `react-bootstrap` and `node-sass` too to the newest available versions, but this does not fix the issue.

What could cause this error? I fail to see how this could be an issue with React 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of digging and thought your issue would be related to this - https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2931 but this bug is related to the interpolation of sass variables into a css variable which causes the same compilation error. They also mention the issues are prevalent when using bootstrap `5.1.3` and `5.2.3`.

Have you considered `node-sass` is deprecated? https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

[image]

Check out this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67161579/cannot-find-module-sass/68327656#68327656) where the user offers to use just `sass` instead. Hopefully moving away from `node-sass` will allow the compilation to work again.